# least square estimators and simple linear regression related proofs

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares, linear-regression

Suppose that we have independent samples ${(x_i,y_i ):i=1,⋯,n}$ which are assumed to follow $ y_i=β_0+β_1 x_i+ε_i $ where $\epsilon_i$  are i.i.d. from $N(0,\sigma^2)$ . 
Suppose that $b_0$ and $b_1$ are the least square estimators of $b_0$ and $b_1$ respectively. Define $y ̂_i=b_0+b_1 x_i$ and $e_i=y_i-y ̂_i$.

Prove each of the following:
[image]

where $s_x^2$ and $s_y^2$ are the sample variances of ${x_i:i=1,⋯,n}$ and ${y_i:i=1,⋯,n}$ respectively, and $s_xy$ is their sample covariance.

I know that this will be a useful fact but I could not figure it out yet
$$y ̂_i=b_0+b_1 x_i=y ̅+b_1 (x_i-x ̅)$$

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. \begin{align}
   SSreg &= \sum ( \hat y - \bar{y} ) ^ 2\\
    & = \sum ( b_0 + b_1 x_i  - b_0 - b_1 \bar x  ) ^ 2\\
   & =  b_1^2\sum (  x_i  - \bar x  ) ^ 2\\
   \end{align}
   and now just replace $b_1$ with its explicit form, which is 
   $$
   \frac{\sum(y_i - \bar y)(x_i - \bar x)}{\sum( x_i - \bar x )^2}.
   $$
2. Use the results from (1) and note that $b_1 = \frac{S_{xy}}{S_x^2}$, thus

\begin{align}
R^2 &= SSreg/SST\\
 & = \frac{b_1 ^ 2 S_{x}^2}{ S_y^2}\\
& =  \frac{S_{xy}^2 S_{x}^2}{ S_x^4S_y^2}\\
& =  \frac{S_{xy}^2 }{ S_x^2S_y^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot. Greatly appreciated (Upvoted!).